# Can infinitive marker, to, be categorized into two meanings?

Tags: infinitives

I get the strong feeling that infinitive marker ‘to’ has two ways of meaning in dictionaries, though it has variety of meaning on them. One is ‘toward something’, the other ‘(just) have passed something.’

For [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/to_2)’s cases, #2,3,6 show having changed from a scene to other one. #1,4,5,7 show facing, heading some targets.

Is it too simplified?

Comment: I suppose you might ask whether the grammaticalization of *to* as an infinitive marker is complete, or whether some traces of its (figurative) meaning as a preposition remain.

Comment: See [*OED 1*](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdictio101murruoft#page/n97/mode/2up), the note headed *History* under category **B.** at the bottom of the middle column. In the last sentences of that note the Editors agree with you; I myself think this very questionable, an instance of the etymological fallacy.

Comment: @StoneyB: I can't easily read the text in that link, but it seems to me it's mainly to do with *how the usage came about*. OP seems concerned with *what it means now*, in which context I think this from current OED is relevant... *To a certain extent, therefore, i.e. when the infinitive is the subject or direct object, **to** has lost **all** its meaning, and become a mere ‘sign’ or prefix of the infinitive.*

Comment: ...but I admit they also say *after an intrans. vb., or the passive voice, **to** is still the preposition. In appearance, there is no difference between the infinitive in ‘he proceeds to speak’ and ‘he chooses to speak’; but in the latter **to speak** is the equivalent of **speaking** or **speech**, and in the former of **to speaking** or **to speech**.* So yes, sometimes there is a "prepositional" element, so sometimes there will be a concept of "direction". But I think splitting "direction" into "towards" and "away" isn't a useful way of looking at current usage in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's just have a look at OALD's examples, grouped as OP suggests...

> ## Set A
>
> 2 (result of something) *She managed to escape.*
>   3 (cause of something) *I'm sorry to hear that.*
>   6 (one action following another) *I reached the station only to find that my train had already left.*
>
> ## Set B
>
> 1 (purpose or intention) *I set out to buy food.*
>   4 (a desired or advised action) *I'd love to go to France this summer.*
>   5 (something known or reported about something) *The house was said to be haunted.*
>   7 (to show that you must or should do something) *You are not to talk during the exam.*

I admit I don't fully understand OP's #A = *going towards something,* #B = *having just passed something*. But logically, I can't see any reason to suppose there should be any way of grouping the examples that *means* anything. To my mind, OALD just provides a (non-exhaustive) list of typical constructions that can include an infinitive form *as well as* a "main verb".

They're not even particularly clear-cut distinct usages anyway. For example...

> *"I tried to buy food"* looks like a variant of #1 *"I set out to buy food."*
>    *"She tried to escape"* looks like a variant of #2 *"She managed to escape."*

It's not obvious to me how *trying to buy food* could be "categorically" different to *trying to escape*, and I don't think OALD is trying to imply anything like that in the way they've presented their examples. There aren't *really* "seven categories" in the first place - but there *is* a broad range of contexts with infinitive verb forms (including [those that don't use "**to**"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bare+infinitive), which obviously aren't on that particular AOLD page). Really, they're just showing a selection of usages to illustrate that range.

OP has identified one possible "higher-level grouping" to collapse OALD's *seven* categories into *two*, but it doesn't really "mean" anything. We could group them in different ways, into the same or a different number of categories. It's just an arbitrary subdivision of typical usages.